# Why a program/browser running without GUI called Headless?

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, headless, google-chrome-headless, headless-browser

I'm curious about why **headless** means "without GUI". What is the etymology of **headless**? It seems there is no relationship between a head and GUI.

Answer (score 2):

Headless in this context would be referred to as "without sight". A chicken without a head, or a company without a head has no head therefore it has no sight, however it can still function. Selenium has headless browser modes for programmers who would like to test code without a browser ui to signify the functionality of a browser without the "consciousness of a user".

First Stack post! Rah!

Answer (score 0):

From [chromium](/questions/tagged/chromium)'s perspective, [Headless Chrome](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/lkgr/headless/README.md) is a way to run the [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) browser in a **headless** environment which is essentially, running Chrome without chrome. It is a tool for automated testing and server environments where you don't need a visible UI shell.

The concept of [Headless Chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=612904) was [implemented](https://codereview.chromium.org/1991953002) through a `--headless` **runtime switch** which would use a regular Chrome binary as a headless. When the binary would be launched with this switch, the main entry-point would call into the *Headless Shell* entry-point, effectively starting that shell instead of Chrome. To make this possible *Chromium Team* removed the dependency from `Headless` to `Ozone` as **Ozone** is a build-time feature which is generally not enabled for regular Chrome builds. Essentially it meant implementing a new headless-specific
`WindowTreeHost` and modifying various graphics and input entrypoints to do something appropriate in headless mode. Though much of the were in platform-specific code, the main aim was to enable the shell to use an in-memory profile which is fully independent of the user’s actual profile.

There are three main changes for `--headless` were:

- Turn Headless Shell into an embeddable library (instead of a standalone app).
- The main Chrome entrypoint should dispatch into the Headless Shell entrypoint when --headless is used, i.e. launching Headless Shell instead of the regular Chrome UI.
- Platform-specific changes to avoid window system dependencies in headless mode.
- Where as the *Cross-platform* changes were in:

  - `chrome/chrome_main.cc`: Dispatch into HeadlessShellMain() when launched with --headless.
  - `content/browser/compositor/gpu_process_transport_factory.cc`: Use a software output device in headless mode.

---

### References

A couple of references:

- [Headless Chrome architecture](https://docs.google.com/document/d/11zIkKkLBocofGgoTeeyibB2TZ_k7nR78v7kNelCatUE/edit#heading=h.1mcyhpdqtjob)
- [Runtime headless mode on Windows OS](https://docs.google.com/document/d/12c3bSEbmpeGevuyFHcvEKw9br6CkFJSS2saQynBjIzE/edit#heading=h.qxqfzv2lj12s)